# Is referencing a real instance of a noun the primary function of determiners as a word class?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, determiners

In almost every case where a determiner/article is used, the noun phrase references an instance of the noun, either imagined or existing. Generally, the opposite is true; noun phrases without determiners reference only the idea or concept of the thing the noun represents, not an instance of it. I think this is a rather vital distinction, especially for language learners. However, in most grammar and linguistic sources I've found, this is rarely mentioned or discussed.

Examples:

> This salt tastes like sulfur.
> (specific determiner - actual instance of salt, no instance of sulfur)
>
> I don’t like salt.
> (no determiner - refers to the concept of salt, not an actual instance)
>
> Give me a pen, please.
> (general determiner - non specific, could be any instance of pen)
>
> My pen is an antique.
> (a specific instance of pen, general instance of antique)
>
> Our cat prefers milk.
> (a real instance of the noun cat, but no actual instance of milk)

Of course, there are exceptions where an instance of a noun is referenced with or without a determiner.

> She was given **custody** of her children by the judge.
>
> This corporate stock comes with **voting rights**.
>
> **Her custody** of the children was mandated by the judge.
>
> **These voting rights** are indispensable.

My question is why is this important feature of determiners not given more primacy in grammar and linguistics?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit on [SO Linguistics?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused here. "a" is a determiner yet you provide examples where it doesn't refer to a specific thing, and "the" can be used in the abstract ("the badger is a fierce creature"). Are you saying this is only true of some determiners, and if so which? Some determiners like possessives and demonstratives commonly refer to real physical things, but other often don't. I suspect this is a rule with too many exceptions to be practical, but maybe you could try and work it up into a system with more examples and fewer exceptions.

Comment: At first glance *In almost every case where a determiner/article is used, the noun phrase references a real world instance of the noun.* seems fair as general guidance. A determiner specifies a noun, i.e. gives a specific (real-world?) noun. However, this may be a little "*post hoc, propter hoc*" as to accept, for example, "the", the noun must already be known to the listener/reader: it must have been defined.

Comment: @StuartF - No, I'm not confused about that. *a pen* is still an extant pen but referred to generally rather than speciically. The whole set of determiners do this, they either make a general or specific reference to things that are extant, even conceptul things like *(her) custody*. Perhaps you could provide some examples where the use of determiners does not reference an extant thing.

Comment: @Greybeard - granted, 'real-world' may not be the best choice of words, but barring existential philosophy, they do indicate by reference something that exists either physically or conceptually. I don't get your reference to logical fallacy - once *a* thing is introduced, it becomes *the* thing, so in either form there is still extancy.

Comment: My opinion is that "the" - as an example - is basically a demonstrative adjective, and like all demonstratives it must be "demonstrated". *This* and *that* are demonstrated by pointing; "**the**" is demonstrated by the listener being aware of the noun. To say that "the" **creates** this distinction is to put the cart before the horse: **the** requires, *ab initio*, that awareness. I would also refer you to "The dog has been mankind's companion for 30,000 years."

Comment: @Greybeard - Ok, I think I see what you mean. I didn't say that determiners **create** the distinction between extant and non-extant nouns. A thing has to exist before we reference it with determiners - they reference a pre-existing (praeexistente if you prefer Latin) distinction. I guess that is what you mean by ab initio (from the beginning) but it means different things in different contexts, including language learning (to learn without prior knowledge = beginner, I guess), so I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: @Greybeard - What I'm actually saying is that noun phrases with determiners reference already existing instances of nouns. Those without determiners do not. But yeah, you got it - you found a refuge for you argument in an exceptional use of determiners that does not reference an instance of a noun, which in no way invalidates the vastly more comon use of determiners to which I am speaking.

Comment: This question was closed because someone thinks it is opinion-based. I don't see an opinion anywhere in the question, so I'm not sure how to address this. I'm supposed to recieve a notification explaining the reason but all I got was - the post was closed because it is opinion based. It's not, and I have voted to reopen this question. Perhaps someone can explain this to me.

Comment: @Greybeard - I've thought about your example, *the dog* and I thik it is not a valid example of the use of a determiner to reference a non-extant noun. The dog, if iterpreted literally, would necesarily be a 30,000 year old dog. Of course it is not interpreted that way because it references the existence of the species of 'dog' which is indeed an extant noun.

Comment: "The dog" in the sense I used it in the example is indeed an abstract noun - a concept without a real existence: it is non-finite as it encompasses all dogs past, present and future. This is why I wrote "seems fair as general guidance" in my first comment - your theory is guidance, not a rule - it is guidance as it has a few exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree that modern grammars tend to over-emphasise the *syntactic* classification of parts of speech (an over-reaction to the former unhelpful simplistic classifications based purely on semantics: 'a noun is the name of a person, place, animal, plant, thing ... [time ... concept ... lack ...]' / 'a verb is a "doing-word" '). I'd argue that not only how words are used in constructions, but also semantics and to some degree morphology, should be factors in POS classification.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) has a reasonable article addressing determiners, giving a broad definition that is largely semantic-based::

> A determiner, also called determinative [by CGEL and others]
> (abbreviated det), is a word, phrase, or affix that occurs together
> with a noun or noun phrase and generally serves to express the
> reference of that noun or noun phrase in the context

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/determiner) also gives a definition mainly based on semantics rather than distribution:

> **determiner** [noun; C] [language: specialised] B2: in grammar, a word that is used before a noun to show which particular example of the
> noun you are referring to:
>
> In the phrases "my first boyfriend" and "that strange woman", the
> words "my" and "that" are determiners.

They are used to identify, to indicate plurality, ownership – properties not so much inherent to the object etc itself ('a *big blue metal* bike') but to how they relate to their environment –

including specificity or lack of it, and [usually imprecise] quantity ('*that* bike', '*your* bike', '*the* bike', '*a* bike', '*several* bikes' –

distributivity ('*every* bike', '*some [not all]* bikes') –

and queries about identification within the environment ('*which* bike?').

But note that adjectives (and attributive nouns) are also used as prenominal classifiers ('chemical reactions', 'forest fire') (identifying the whole subclass involved) and identifiers ('Pass me the *blue* folder, please'; 'Don't buy the *expensive* one') (identifying within a local group).

So determiners certainly bring out some relation of the referent to the real world, often particularising, but they are not alone in doing this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a thoughtful answer. Yes, 'chemical reactions' and 'forest fires' are so general, so categorical as to not indicate a general or specific instance of them but rather just the idea of them - they exist but are not instantiated by the phrase. Adjectives, participles and attributive nouns do not instantiate, they describe. Only determiners instantiate the noun and if I'm not wrong about this, they all do, no matter what subcategory of determiner they belong to.

Comment: Determiners like 'some', 'few', 'many' (and 'no') restrict the size of the set under consideration rather than meaningfully identify a referent within the set. And 'enough' introduces 'a sufficient number of'.

Comment: Yes, I saw that with 'some' when I was thinking about this but is it correct that these don't have at least a general referent, even if we can't tell which item in the set is being referenced? "Some dude" amongst the larger set of dudes is still an extant dude, is he not? Ok, 'no dude' seems valid. That;s good, you made me smile.

Comment: That's one of the ways 'some' is used. In the usual quantifier sense (some eggs, some flour) it is used to mean 'a reasonable-within-context number/amount of' and addresses quantity rather than being a particuliser. _That last word may still need scare quotes; it's not too common (in English) on the internet._

Comment: Determiners are broadly categorized as either specific or non-specific, and in most cases they reference an extant (or imagined?) instance of the noun. I doubt that there are many exceptions to this, but your use of "no" is clearly one. I would say that "some eggs," as one example, could reference an extant or non-extant quantity of eggs and interestingly, it seems to depend on the verb used. Consider the difference between, "We needed/ wanted/ expected some rain," and "We had/ experienced/ got some rain." Or, "Some rain will fall today," and "Some rain fell today.," where tense is a factor.

Comment: @UbuEnglish To be honest, it sounds like you're trying to keep redefining the word "instance" to keep your hypothesis intact; eventually, explaining what counts as an "instance" will be no easier than explaining what counts as a "determiner."

Comment: @alphabet - I'm simply making refinements in my observations. I'm not redefining anything. Whether an instance of a noun is imagined or extant doesn't matter - it's the determiner that makes the reference. It's the same with verbs, by the way - finite verbs are imagined or real instances of verbs and non finite ones are conceptual, they are not instantiated.